# Code 9: Firebase Scheduled Export - 'The requested snapshot version is too old.'

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have encountered a new error that has recently occurred. As part of a scheduled backup function, I explore a copy go each datastore and save in a bucket for later use. The following syntax has worked well over the last year, however, I suspect due to load, has now stopped working.

```
async function getDataStore(collection) {
  return admin.firestore().collection(collection).get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
      if (querySnapshot.size == 0) {
        console.log('No matching request for: ' + collection);
        return []
      } else {
        const data = [];

        //Query snapshot line throwing snapshot too old error.
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
          let data_temp = doc.data();
          data_temp.doc_id = doc.id;
          data.push(data_temp);
        });

        return data;
      }
    });
}
```

This now throws a code 9, the requested snapshot version is too old.  One way I can think of overcoming this, would be to batch the request into smaller 'chunks' and save. however, I wanted to see if there was something more efficient I may be missing. Fresh eyes are always helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to indicate the line of code that causes the problem.  Ideally, there will be enough information in the question that anyone can use to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Added a line comment to highlight where the issue occurs.

Comment: having the same issue, did you find a solution by now @Dan?

Comment: @Thomas - the way I avoided this issue was to batch my request using promise pool. I made only 500 queries per request, and iterated through unit I obtained all the data.  Not ideal for my use case, but worked.