# Firestore GET query Error: 9 FAILED_PRECONDITION: The requested snapshot version is too old

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I am performing a query to get data from Firestore. I am doing it for 20K+ files.

- First, I used the get() method , but it didn't work.
- Then, I tried to do the same using [stream](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/CollectionReference.html#stream).
  It is working sometimes and sometimes not.
- Now, the only solution that I have is probably to use limit() with get().

What I wanted to ask is what are the best practices for doing larger reads from Firestore or If anyone has done the same in the past can also share their approach. It would be quite helpful.

Comment: Hi @Shobit Jain,Please let me know if the answer was helpful or you need any further information.

Answer (score 0):

How soon is this error observed, once you start your process? It seems this is hitting some product timeout due to a large dataset, please be advised on the performance best practices on snapshot usage here[4].

After investigating further in terms of workarounds, please consider going through the following additional approaches :

1. By paginating the data as mentioned here[1].
2. By batching or splitting up the request[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65224130/code-9-firebase-scheduled-export-the-requested-snapshot-version-is-too-old#:%7E:text=issue%20was%20to-,batch%20my%20request,-using%20promise%20pool).
3. Instead of using a document snapshot you can use real time updates like[3]

[1] : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60175102/the-requested-snapshot-version-is-too-old-error-in-firestore#:~:text=by%20paginating%20the%20data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60175102/the-requested-snapshot-version-is-too-old-error-in-firestore#:%7E:text=by%20paginating%20the%20data)

[3] : https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen

[4] : https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/best-practices#realtime_updates